# How can we add referer in the exoplayer android java

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, referer

I want to play this link but i m unable to play this link in my exoplayer

I will be able to play this link only when this referer will be added in the exoplayer but i m unable to add this referer. I dont know how can i add this referer to my exoplayer

Referer: http://nbajunkie.xyz/jp1/

https://reels2watch.com/hls/s1.m3u8

```
dataSourceFactory.getDefaultRequestProperties().set("Referer", "https://yourdomain.com");
```

I dont know how to add this referer in the header can someone help me about it or Anyone can do it for me ? Because i don’t know much about java kindly let me know how to solve this issue.

```
import static com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util.getUserAgent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.RenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.DefaultMediaSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DefaultDashChunkSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.DefaultSsChunkSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.SsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaLoadOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaMetadata;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastButtonFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastSession;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastState;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastStateListener;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.SessionManagerListener;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.RemoteMediaClient;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.Myapp.hd.Steaming.R;
import com.Myapp.hd.Steaming.HelperClass;
import com.Myapp.hd.Steaming.BaseActivity;
import com.Myapp.hd.Steaming.Location;
import com.Myapp.hd.Steaming.sessionManager.SessionManager;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Exo_Player extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Exo_Player";
    String url, userAgent;
    boolean tokenEnable = false;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter BANDWIDTH_METER = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    private DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory;
    private Handler mainHandler;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        setContentView(R.layout.exo_player_ui);
        castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
        initCast();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(Exo_Player.this, sessionManager.getBackads(), adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        interstitial = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        interstitial = null;
                    }
                });


        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        processToken();

        listenCast();




    }

    MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton;
    CastContext castContext;
    RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient;

    public boolean initCast() {
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.url));
        userAgent = getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.user_agent));
        tokenEnable = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(getString(R.string.t_enable), false);

        mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), mediaRouteButton);
        if (castContext == null)
            castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);

        castContext.addCastStateListener(new CastStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCastStateChanged(int state) {
                /*if (state == CastState.NO_DEVICES_AVAILABLE) {
//                    mediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if(state==CastState.CONNECTING) {
                    showToast("Connecting");
                } else*/ if (state == CastState.CONNECTED) {
//                    showToast("Connected");
//                    castMetadata();
                    openCastPlayer();
                }/* else if (mediaRouteButton.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    mediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }*/
            }
        });
        if (castContext.getCastState() == CastState.CONNECTED) {
            openCastPlayer();
            return true;
        } else {
//                showToast("not connected");
        }
        if (castContext.getCastState() != CastState.NO_DEVICES_AVAILABLE)
            mediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }

    private void registerListener() {
        if (mCastContext != null) {

            mCastContext.getSessionManager().addSessionManagerListener(
                    mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);
        }
    }

    private void unRegisterListener() {
        if (mCastContext != null) {
            mCastContext.getSessionManager().removeSessionManagerListener(
                    mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);
        }
    }


    private void showToast(String connecting) {
        Toast.makeText(this, connecting, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private void processToken() {
        if (!HelperClass.isValid(url) || !tokenEnable) {
            init("");
            return;
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        enqueue(getLocInterface().getLoc(sessionManager.getToken(), hashMap), new CallBack<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                super.onComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                super.onError(e);
                Toast.makeText(Exo_Player.this,
                        "Failed to process url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NotNull Location location) {
                super.onNext(location);
                if (location.appendResult != null)
                    init(location.appendResult);
            }
        });
    }

    private void init(String s) {


        url += s;

        Log.e(TAG, "init: new url is " + url);
        mediaDataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory(true);

        mainHandler = new Handler();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        RenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this);

//        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
//        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

//        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, renderersFactory).setLoadControl(loadControl).build();


        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exoPlayerView);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        playerView.setUseController(true);
        playerView.requestFocus();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        final MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri, null);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(@NotNull TrackGroupArray trackGroups, @NotNull TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTracksChanged: " + trackGroups.length);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIsLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingChanged: " + isLoading);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: " + playWhenReady);
                if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(@NotNull PlaybackException error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerError: ", error);
                player.stop();
//                errorDialog();
                player.prepare(mediaSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);


            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPositionDiscontinuity: true");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(@NotNull PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });

        Log.d("INFO", "ActivityVideoPlayer");

    }


    private void pausePlayer() {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        player.getPlaybackState();
    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        player.getPlaybackState();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            unRegisterListener();
            pausePlayer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        try {
            registerListener();
            if (HelperClass.vpn(this)) {
                finish();
            }
            startPlayer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy()...");
        if (player != null)
            player.release();
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, String overrideExtension) {
        int type = TextUtils.isEmpty(overrideExtension) ? Util.inferContentType(uri)
                : Util.inferContentType("." + overrideExtension);
        switch (type) {
            case C.TYPE_SS:
                return new SsMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultSsChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), buildDataSourceFactory(false)).createMediaSource(uri);
            case C.TYPE_DASH:
                return new DashMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), buildDataSourceFactory(false)).createMediaSource(uri);
            case C.TYPE_HLS:
                return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
            case C.TYPE_OTHER:
                return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
            default: {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
            }
        }
    }


    private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
        return buildDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);
    }

    public DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
        return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, bandwidthMeter,
                buildHttpDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter));
    }


    public HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {


        String s = "xxxxx";
        if (userAgent != null && !userAgent.isEmpty()) {
            s = userAgent;
        }
        return new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(getUserAgent2(this, s), bandwidthMeter);

    }



    public static String getUserAgent2(Context context, String applicationName) {
        return applicationName
                + "";
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (interstitial != null) {
            interstitial.show(Exo_Player.this);
        }
        if (player != null)
            player.stop();
    }

//    public void errorDialog() {
//        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
//                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
//                .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_oops))
//                .setCancelable(false)
//                .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_failed))
//                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.option_retry), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                        retryLoad();
//                  z  }
//
//                })
//                .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.option_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
//                        finish();
//                    }
//                })
//                .show();
//    }

//    public void retryLoad() {
//        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
//        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri, null);
//        player.prepare(mediaSource);
//        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
//    }

    public void castplayer(String name, String link, String unique, String img) {

        if (!isCastApiAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        Context context = this;
        CastSession castSession = CastContext.getSharedInstance(context).getSessionManager()
                .getCurrentCastSession();
        if (castSession.isConnected()) {

            MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_GENERIC);
            movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, name);



            MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(link)
                    .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                    .setEntity(unique)
                    .build();

            final RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient = castSession.getRemoteMediaClient();
            if (remoteMediaClient == null) {
//                Timber.tag(TAG).w("showQueuePopup(): null RemoteMediaClient");
                return;
            }

            if (remoteMediaClient.isPlaying()) {
                MediaInfo curMedia = remoteMediaClient.getMediaInfo();
                if (curMedia != null && curMedia.getEntity().equals(unique)) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (remoteMediaClient.isLoadingNextItem() || remoteMediaClient.isBuffering()) {
                return;
            }
//            final QueueDataProvider provider = QueueDataProvider.getInstance(context);
//            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, binding.epLayout);
//            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(
//                    provider.isQueueDetached() || provider.getCount() == 0
//                            ? R.menu.detached_popup_add_to_queue
//                            : R.menu.popup_add_to_queue, popup.getMenu());
//            PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener clickListener = menuItem -> {
//            QueueDataProvider provider1 = QueueDataProvider.getInstance(context);
//            MediaQueueItem queueItem = new MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).setAutoplay(
//                    false).setPreloadTime(2).build();
//            MediaQueueItem[] newItemArray = new MediaQueueItem[]{queueItem};
//            String toastMessage = null;
//            if (provider1.isQueueDetached() && provider1.getCount() > 0) {
//                    if ((menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_play_now)
//                            || (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_add_to_queue)) {
//                MediaQueueItem[] items = Utils
//                        .rebuildQueueAndAppend(provider1.getItems(), queueItem);
//                remoteMediaClient.queueLoad(items, provider1.getCount(),
//                        MediaStatus.REPEAT_MODE_REPEAT_OFF, null);
//                    } else {
//                        return false;
//                    }
//            } else {
//                if (provider1.getCount() == 0) {
//                    remoteMediaClient.queueLoad(newItemArray, 0,
//                            MediaStatus.REPEAT_MODE_REPEAT_OFF, null);
//                } else {
//                    int currentId = provider1.getCurrentItemId();
////                        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_play_now) {
//                    remoteMediaClient.queueInsertAndPlayItem(queueItem, currentId, null);
            remoteMediaClient.load(mediaInfo, new MediaLoadOptions.Builder().build());


//                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_play_next) {
//                            int currentPosition = provider1.getPositionByItemId(currentId);
//                            if (currentPosition == provider1.getCount() - 1) {
//                                //we are adding to the end of queue
//                                remoteMediaClient.queueAppendItem(queueItem, null);
//                            } else {
//                                int nextItemId = provider1.getItem(currentPosition + 1).getItemId();
//                                remoteMediaClient.queueInsertItems(newItemArray, nextItemId, null);
//                            }
//                            toastMessage = context.getString(
//                                    R.string.queue_item_added_to_play_next);
//                        } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_add_to_queue) {
//                            remoteMediaClient.queueAppendItem(queueItem, null);
//                            toastMessage = context.getString(R.string.queue_item_added_to_queue);
//                        } else {
//                            return false;
//                        }
//                }
//            }
//                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_play_now) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExpandedControlsActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
//                }
//            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(toastMessage)) {
//                Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//                return true;
//            };
//            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(clickListener);
//            popup.show();
//        }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    private CastContext mCastContext;
    private CastSession mCastSession;
    private SessionManagerListener<CastSession> mSessionManagerListener;

    private void listenCast() {
        if (!isCastApiAvailable()) {
            return;
        }
        setupCastListener();
        mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
        mCastSession = mCastContext.getSessionManager().getCurrentCastSession();
    }

    private void setupCastListener() {
        mSessionManagerListener = new SessionManagerListener<CastSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnded(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();
                mCastContext = null;
                mCastSession = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumed(CastSession session, boolean wasSuspended) {
                onApplicationConnected(session);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResumeFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
                onApplicationConnected(session);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
                onApplicationDisconnected();

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionStarting(CastSession session) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionEnding(CastSession session) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionResuming(CastSession session, String sessionId) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSessionSuspended(CastSession session, int reason) {

            }

            private void onApplicationConnected(CastSession castSession) {
                mCastSession = castSession;
                openCastPlayer();
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            private void onApplicationDisconnected() {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
    }

    private void openCastPlayer() {
        castplayer(getString(R.string.app_name), url, url, url);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1619#issuecomment-227915284 https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8292

Answer (score 1):

I remember that was changed with the newer updates at some point last year. Now you need to pass a map to `setDefaultRequestProperties` after building a `HttpDataSource`. Using a [`DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory.html) should be enough if you are not considering using a custom one.